# Excel Data management / Macro creation

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to automate a process and collate the information.

Column A - Timestamps

Column B - Current Meter

Column C - Shadow    Meter

I want excel to select Column A - take all of the timestamps from the same day

Select column B and subtract column C.

Give an output into column D.

There are around 178000 timestamps from 10/10/2017 - 14/02/2018

I want to know what the daily difference between each column is.

How do i get excel to automate this process

and a bonus print out a graph with the information on.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA for that kind of stuff. This can be done with formulas or pivot tables with just a few clicks. You may want to upskill on what Excel can do out of the box.